# How to load a large array of strings in to an MFC combobox control fast as possible?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, combobox, arrays

I have an array of 1000 strings to load into a combo box. What is the fastest way to load the array of strings into the combo box?

Is there some way other than iterating over the list of strings, putting each string into the combo box one at a time?

And how to copy the combo box data once loaded to some 10 other combo boxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have 1,000 strings repeated in 10 comboboxes, you may want to consider using an owner drawn combobox, which draws the strings on the fly based on indices into your array, rather than storing them in the combobox at all.  Way faster, way more memory efficient.  Check out the **DrawItem** method and **DRAWITEMSTRUCT** structure in the on-line help. Basically, you would do something like using **InitStorage** and **InsertString** (as mentioned by NuSonic) to create your 1000 blank items in your combobx, and override **DrawItem** to extract and draw the required string, based on index, as it needs to be drawn.

Comment: This is a pain, but this is the fast way... +1

Comment: It will get the job done.. I wouldn't have thought of this. Bravo

Comment: I'm suffering from the same problem - I have 256 combo boxes which I need to populate each with 10 items. Each combobox takes 2-3 ms to populate. I'm doing everything suggested above - should it really be taking 2-3ms to insert 16 empty items into a combobox?

Comment: Not sure how long it should take but the performance of much of MFC can be pretty terrible.  A possible workaround is to broaden the scope of your 256 comboboxes so they're either global or part of a class that persists longer, so they don't get initialised and deleted that often.

Comment: Old thread (pun intended), but if you're loading 256 unique comboboxes then threading could help, if you have a threadsafe codebase.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any way to load multiple strings atomically, but there are a couple of things that you can do to make the process more efficient:

- Call CComboBox::InitStorage before adding items to pre-allocate memory
- Use InsertString instead of AddString to prevent triggering a sort on each addition (assuming the CBS_SORT style is enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly faster than CComboBox with DrawItem would be an [owner data CListCtrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye4z8x58(VS.80).aspx).
This would also serve your goal of duplicating a subset of the items into other lists, since a common data source could be used.

I suggest this because a 1000-item CComboBox isn't going to be very usable.

Answer (score 0):

I will consider using a pick list instead of a combo box for performance.

A general rule of thumb to improve performance when inserting many item in a UI list is to call before the insertion and setting it back to true after.

Here's the correct syntax

```
#define NB_ITEM 1000
#define ITEM_LENGTH 10

void CMFCComboDlg::InitMyCombo()
{
    CString _strData;
    m_cbMyCombo.SetRedraw( FALSE );

    m_cbMyCombo.Clear();

    m_cbMyCombo.InitStorage(NB_ITEM, ITEM_LENGTH); 

    for( int i = 0; i < NB_ITEM; i++ )
    {
        _strData.Format( L"Test %ld", i );
        m_cbMyCombo.InsertString( i, _strData );
    }

    m_cbMyCombo.SetCurSel(0);

    m_cbMyCombo.SetRedraw( TRUE );
}
```

EDIT: Improve the solution to include smacl suggestion

Comment: This question specifically refers to MFC, which has no such mechanism.

Comment: @nusonic - Yes it does, CWnd::SetRedraw (or WM_SETREDRAW). Which is actually a good suggestion. Too bad Hapkido is speaking a different language then Win32/MFC (What the check is a "pick list" anyway?)

Comment: A pick list is a kind of search dialog optimized to get the data you want quickly.  Browsing through over a thousand record is really not effective.

Comment: @Hapkido, simple mod to improve your above code would be to add an m_cbMyCombo.InitStorage(1000,10000); after SetRedraw,  Agreed that 1000 items is too big for a Combo box and an alternate UI would be a good idea.

Comment: InitStorage is a good suggestion, I included it in my solution.  However, the syntax is  
int InitStorage(int nNbItems, UINT nBytesPerItem );

Comment: I'll second the SetRedraw function call.  Even for small combo box lists (40 items), it makes a difference if you disable redraw before updating the combo.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it in two ways, depending on the # items.  Setting to not draw and init storage made no difference whatsoever to me.  Making an owner draw one is also viable, but I had a ton of comboboxes.  Assuming a fixed list for each combobox, that does not change contents, list is set once.

Very large # Items:
Made the combo box just be Simple/Disabled with SetWindowText to set initial string, and a little button next to it opened a dialog that let you choose the item from a list control in Report mode of the data that would've been in the combo box (could be anything done in dialog).

Moderate # Items:
Made a custom derived combobox class that overrides AddString, SelectString, and handles OnDropDown.  When you add items, it puts them into a temporary vector, and then on SelectString (could do SetCurSel override too), it adds one item it finds and selects.  When dropping down, then it resets the combobox and adds all the items the and selects currently selected one.  There is slight slowdown on dropping the combobox, but on low amounts of items is not noticeable.

It made my dialogs load much faster and still be fully functional without owner draw.